# AngularJS : How to use ng-repeat with in the templateURL of directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created a directive to display the "dropdown". Following are the code i used

HTML

```
<km-sselect km-left-title="Left" km-right-title="Right" km-model="sdsd" km-option="['AA','BB']"></km-sselect>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('kmSselect', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'select.html',
    scope:true,

    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.leftTitle='';
            if(angular.isUndefined(attr.kmLeftTitle)) {
              scope.leftTitle='';
            }
            else {
               scope.leftTitle=attr.kmLeftTitle+"  ";
            }
      scope.rightTitle='';
            if(angular.isUndefined(attr.kmRightTitle)) {
              scope.rightTitle='';
            }
            else {
               scope.rightTitle="  "+attr.kmRightTitle ;
            }

      var str1="n in ";
      var str2=attr.kmOption;
      var str3=attr.kmModel;
      scope.model=attr.kmModel;
      scope.repeat=str1.concat(str2);
      scope.result=str1.concat(str3);

    }
  }
})
```

Select.html

```
<div>
  <div ng-switch on="format">
    <div ng-switch-when="kmForm">
      <div>
        <div class="floatLeft">
          {{leftTitle}}
          Repeat={{repeat}}
      </div>

      <select multiple ng-model="fdg" ng-click="testfunc(attrs.kmModel)">
        <option ng-repeat={{repeat}} value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>{{rightTitle}}</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="kmPreview">
    <div>
      <div class="floatLeft">
        title
        result
      </div>
      <div class="floatLeft box">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="result" class="hrline">{{n}}</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not getting the values populated in "Dropdown".

Can anyone tell me where i went wrong

Answer (score 1):

The way you're trying to solve the problem looks complicated, and is probably difficult to implement.

Why not just create an isolate scope? (the directive looks like it's reusable, so you *should* use isolate scope to prevent unintended consequences).

In that case, you can two-way bind the options and the model, and just pass them on to the ng-model and ng-select inside the template inside the directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a select you need to use the directive ng-option for the looping functionality and not ng-repeat. Check the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

```
<select multiple ng-model="fdg" ng-click="testfunc(attrs.kmModel)" ng-options={{repeat}}></select>
```

However this has a funny smell to it and I dont think it will work as the ng-options will be fired before the {{repeat}} has a chance to be rendered.

I would recommend pulling this select into its own directive so it complies everything all in one go this might solve the potential code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Before `release` can be converted to `n in ['AA','BB']`, `ng-repeat` has already determined that it has an [invalid expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/iexp?p0=repeat).

The solution is to create a scope value for the collection in the link function, then your template can reference it in a standard `ng-repeat` expression.  To do this, use `$eval` to convert the attribute from a string into an object.

```
scope.kmOption = scope.$eval(attr.kmOption);
```

Now you can just write a typical expression in select.html:

```
<option ng-repeat="n in kmOption" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
```

And, as others have said, you are typically better off using `ng-options` with `select`, but the same fix is necessary:

```
<select multiple ng-model="$parent.kmModel" ng-options="n for n in kmOption"></select>
```

---

**Update**
You can avoid using the `link` function to `$eval` the options if you rewrite your directive like this:

```
app.directive('kmSselect', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'select.html',
    scope: {
      kmModel: '=',
      format: '=',
      kmLeftTitle: '@',
      kmRightTitle: '@',
      kmOption: '@'
    }
  }
})
```

And change the template so that `kmOption` is interpolated:

```
<select ng-model="$parent.kmModel" ng-options="n for n in {{kmOption}}"></select>
```

If you want to try the code for yourself, [here is a working demo on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/l0Fmww0V2YhZQN0r7zfh?p=preview).

**Side Note**
I am surprised that this works, actually, given that `ng-repeat` won't allow similar usage (as discussed above): `ng-repeat="n in {{kmOption}}"`.

Comment: I saw your plunker, it is good, but when i remove the "multiple" in select.html. The empty item is coming on the list. Can you help me to remove that empty value

Comment: yes, i updated the plunker to get binding working.  please take a look

Comment: It is working good, thanks. Is it possible to do the same without using "link" in directive